# FAB Button does not have backdrop to close when theuser clicks outside the options

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to add css backdrop which allows the user to close FAB button options once it's clicked. I tried the following CSS solution from [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/fab-button-backdrop/80019/5) but covers the options and cannot be seeing.

```
<button ion-button (click)="toggle!=toggle ">Add</button>
<div [ngClass]="{ 'blur' : toggle }">
your content
</div>


<!-- fab placed to the bottom & center -->
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button (click)="toggle!=toggle ">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-dropup"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
      <ion-fab-list side="top">
      <ion-fab-button><ion-icon name="logo-vimeo"></ion-icon></ion-fab-button>
      <ion-fab-button><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></ion-fab-button>
      <ion-fab-button><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></ion-fab-button>
      <ion-fab-button><ion-icon name="restaurant"></ion-icon>
        <div class="list-label">Meals</div>
      </ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab-list>
  </ion-fab>

<div [ngClass]="{ 'blur' : toggle }">
  <ion-content
    <ion-card class="welcome-card">
      <ion-img src="/assets/shapes.svg"></ion-img>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle>Get Started</ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-card-title>Welcome to Ionic</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p>Now that your app has been created, you'll want to start building out features and components. Check out some of the resources below for next steps.</p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-content
</div>
```

CSS

```
.blur {
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    transition: -webkit-filter 200ms linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar thing in our app, but we use the backdrop as a loading screen with animations inside. I used a separate component with a high `z-index:50` and if I want to have something on a higher level, I just add a lager number to the `z-index` of that element. I have ran some tests and it should work with `ion-fab`.